# ErrorException in FieldsController.php line 173: Trying to get property of non-objec

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**this mycontroler**

```
      public function index(Request $request, Builder $htmlBuilder)
    {
      if ($request->ajax())
      {
        $fields = Field::select(['id','id_lapangan','nama_lapangan','harga_sewa','gambar']);
        return Datatables::of($fields)
        ->addColumn('action', function($field){
          return view('datatable._action', [
            'model' => $field,
            'form_url'=>route('fields.destroy', $field->id),
            'edit_url'=>route('fields.edit', $field->id),
            'confirm_message'=>'yakin mau hapus '.$field->nama_lapangan .'?'
          ]);
        })
        ->make(true);
      }
```

**This error occurs when I delete or update data,**

```
          public function destroy($id) {
            $field=Field::find($id);
            if($field->gambar){
              $old_gambar = $field->gambar;
              $filepath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img'
              . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $field->gambar;
              try {
                File::delete($filepath);
              }catch (FileNotFoundException $e){
              //file sudah di hapus/tidak Ada
            }
        }
        $field->delete();
        Session::flash("flash_notification",[
          "level"=>"success",
          "message"=>"Berhasil menghapus lapangan"
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('fields.index');
    }
    }
```

**this is my action blade**

```
      {!! Form::model($model, ['url'=> $form_url, 'method' => 'delete' ,
     'class' => 'form-inline js-confirm','data-confirm'=>$confirm_message]) !!}
    <a href="{{ $edit_url}}">Ubah</a> |
    {!! Form::submit('Hapus', ['class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-danger']) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**and this error occurs when i click button delete and update,
some time its work but delete data with no selected id,**

Comment: Point out line 173 in the controller

Comment: Share us the code in line 173 of the `FieldsController.php`